SPI read nothing on ftd2232H
I use python doing register read/write action by SPI.
I check the MOSI/MISO waveform by scope and it is as expected.
address = 0x80b6, value = 0x0962(as expected)
write address = 0x80b6
read value = 0x0962
The behavior of above picture looks correct and is as expected.
But the value from read() response is nothing...
readbyte is 0...
I follow the setting process from another VB program made by predecessor. I can get the right value using that VB program, means I wrote 0x80b6(addr) to device and also got 0x0962(value) from device.
But this python code can't get the value 0x0962.
Below is my code, thank you very much in advance!
import ftd2xx as ftd


class GR_FT2232_SPI:
    def __init__(self, index):
        self.d = ftd.open(index)  # 0 = ADBUS, 1 = BDBUS

    def ftd_spi_init(self):
        self.d.resetDevice()  # Reset USB device
        # self.d.setUSBParameters(65535, 65535)  # Set USB request transfer sizes to 64K
        self.d.setChars(False, 0, False, 0)  # Disable event and error characters
        self.d.setTimeouts(3000, 3000)  # Sets the read and write timeouts in milliseconds
        # self.d.setLatencyTimer(4)  # Set the latency timer to 1mS (default is 16mS)
        self.d.setFlowControl(0x0100, 0, 0)
        self.d.setBitMode(0x0, 0x00)  # Reset controller
        self.d.setBitMode(0x0, 0x02)  # Enable MPSSE mode
        self.ftd_spi_clkcfg()
        self.d.write(bytes(0x85))  # Command to turn off loop back of TDI/TDO connection

    def ftd_spi_clkcfg(self):
        sentbuffer = (0x8a, 0x97, 0x8d)
        self.d.write(bytes(sentbuffer))
        sentbuffer = (0x86, 0x4, 0x0)
        self.d.write(bytes(sentbuffer))

    def rf_spi_r_1(self, addr):
        data = hex(addr).replace('0x', '')
        data_hb = data[:2]
        data_lb = data[-2:]

        sentbuffer = (
            0x80, 0x80, 0xff,
            0x11, 0x1, 0x0,
            int(data_hb, 16), int(data_lb, 16),
            0x80, 0x80, 0xfb,
            0x20, 0x1, 0x0,
            0x80, 0x80, 0xff,
            0x80, 0x0, 0xff
        )
        self.d.write(bytes(sentbuffer))
        byteRead = self.d.getQueueStatus()
        print(byteRead)
        buffRead = self.d.read(byteRead)
        print(buffRead)
        return buffRead


if __name__ == '__main__':
    adbus = GR_FT2232_SPI(0)  # 0(ADBUS)/1(BDBUS)
    adbus.ftd_spi_init()
    a = adbus.rf_spi_r_1(0x80b6)


Please let us know what OS environment you are working in.  Also, what version of Python are you running.  If you are receiving error messages, please edit the question to include the full mesdsage.
